# Accessing GLPK options through PuLP on Google Colab Notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory, pulp, glpk

I am trying to solve a LP problem using PuLP on a Google Colab Notebook. To produce a sensitivity report, I want to use the `'--ranges filename.txt'` option of the GLPK solver. I have installed both PuLP and GLPK as follows:

```
!pip install pulp
!apt-get install -y -qq glpk-utils
```

Here is a small example I'm trying to solve:

```
from pulp import *

prob = LpProblem('Test_Problem',LpMaximize) # Model

x1=LpVariable("x1",0,100) #Variables
x2=LpVariable("x2",0,100)

prob += 5*x1 + 10*x2 # Objective

prob += x1 + 5*x2 <= 500 #Constraints
prob += 2*x1 + 3*x2 <= 200

prob.solve(GLPK(options=[])) # Solve Without '--ranges sensitivity.txt'

print("Status : ", LpStatus[prob.status]) # Output
print("Objective : ", value(prob.objective))
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name," : ", v.varValue)
```

This runs fine and gives me the desired output. However, if I use 'options' and change the following line

```
prob.solve(GLPK(options=['--ranges sensitivity.txt']))
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pulp/apis/glpk_api.py in actualSolve(self, lp)
     91 
     92         if not os.path.exists(tmpSol):
---> 93             raise PulpSolverError("PuLP: Error while executing "+self.path)
     94         status, values = self.readsol(tmpSol)
     95         lp.assignVarsVals(values)

PulpSolverError: PuLP: Error while executing glpsol
```

I have checked that the same code with 'options' works fine on my computer and produces the correct `sensitivity.txt` file. But for some reason, it is not working on Colab. (I've installed GLPK using conda-forge in my laptop.)

What can I do to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `options` argument to pass to GLPK_CMD need to have no spaces, so:

```py
prob.solve(GLPK(msg=True, options=['--ranges', 'sensitivity.txt']))
```

Then it works. With your cases, GLPK gave an error without solving the problem saying:

```
Invalid option '--ranges sensitivity.txt'; try glpsol --help
```